# Undefined data constructor "?" in Hugs intepreter

Tags: haskell, hugs

Strange error when attempting to load file into hugs:

```
Hugs> :l test.hs
ERROR "test.hs":3 - Undefined data constructor "?"
```

Full content of file (yes, one line):

```
test :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

---

Note: Attempting to load the same file in ghci doesn't work either, but for reasons that *make sense*:

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:1:1:
The type signature for ‘test’ lacks an accompanying binding
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: The hugs error is weird.  ghci makes sense, you have only written a type signature for `test`, it needs a definition also, for example `test xs = (xs, xs)`  (which is probably not what you were going for, but it will typecheck at least)

Comment: @luqui You should make your comment as an answer.

Comment: Hugs hasn't been maintained since 2006 or so. Very few people use it any more, and you probably shouldn't either.

Comment: I'm going to make a totally unsubstantiated *guess* that your source code file starts with a Unicode byte-order-mark, which Hugs has no idea what the hell that is, and displays it as "?".

Comment: I installed hugs just to try to reproduce this excellent error message, but all I got was a boring `ERROR "test.hs":1 - Missing binding for variable "test" in type signature`. I suspect your file is not really just one line. (Or hugs is somehow reading uninitialized memory past the end of the file?)

Comment: I see this has been basically answered, but what line is test on here? Line 3? or is line 3 the last line in your file?